# Remapping Emacs Commands

Tags: emacs, elisp, key-bindings, remap

I want to remap `forward-sexp` to `matlab-forward-sexp` in `matlab-mode`.

Currently I do this:

```
(define-key matlab-mode-map [remap forward-sexp] 'matlab-forward-sexp-safe)
```

but when I type `M-x forward-sexp` in matlab-mode I still get the old behaviour. Why? Does it only work when I call `forward-sexp` through a keyboard shortcut?

when I type `C-h f forward-sexp` everything seems ok:

```
forward-sexp is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `lisp.el'.

It is remapped to `matlab-forward-sexp-safe', which is bound to C-M-f,
<C-M-right>, ESC <C-right>.

(forward-sexp &optional ARG)



For more information check the manuals.

Move forward across one balanced expression (sexp).
With ARG, do it that many times.  Negative arg -N means
move backward across N balanced expressions.
This command assumes point is not in a string or comment.

This function is advised.

After-advice `ctx-flash'.

[back]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to change the behavior of the function, you can use `forward-sexp-function`.

Also you may like to check out Emacs-24's octave-mode, which uses SMIE for parsing, making forward-sexp automatically jump over actual Octave syntactic elements rather than only parens/brackets/braces.

Comment: What does SMIE mean? A parsing infrastructure?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the `[remap]` syntax is explicitly for key bindings. When a binding would have invoked the old function, the remapping causes it to invoke the new one instead. That does not alter the definitions of either function, however -- they can still be called directly.

For details, see <kbd>M-:</kbd> `(info "(elisp) Remapping Commands")` <kbd>RET</kbd>

A recent change in Emacs 24 has clarified this help text, so it would now read as follows:

> forward-sexp is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `lisp.el'.
>
> Its keys are remapped to `matlab-forward-sexp-safe'.  Without this remapping,
> it would be bound to C-M-f,
> <C-M-right>, ESC <C-right>.
> .

Comment: +1 @Nordlöw: also note the name of the function you used to do the remapping: (define-*key* ...). That already gives you a hint that the remapping only applies to keyboard shortcuts.